# Excel Multiple Range IF AND Formula

Tags: excel

I am trying to write an xl formula which tests a cell's, `L105` in this case, value against a range and when true applies a hard coded multiplier to the cells value, like this in pseudo code:

- If L105 == 1 then L105*1050
- If L105 2-5 then L105*750
- If L105 6-10 then L105*700
- IF L105 11-15 then L105*650
- IF L105 > 15 then L105*600

So I have written this string of IF and AND statements, which I'm thinking should work ok, but does not and I cannot understand why not:

`=IF(L105=1),L105*1050,IF(AND(L105>1,L105<6),L105*750,IF(AND(L105>5,L105<11),L105*700,IF(AND(L105>10,L105<16),L105*650,IF(L105>15),L105*600)))`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above. Rather unhelpfully the 'error' that i get is a 'formula parse error'.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=IF(L105=1)` ends the IF with the `)`

You also do not need the AND as IF will stop once the it finds true

so:

```
=IF(L105=1,L105*1050,IF(L105<6,L105*750,IF(L105<11,L105*700,IF(L105<16,L105*650,L105*600))))
```

But try this:

```
=L105 * INDEX({1050,750,700,650,600},MATCH(L105,{1,2,6,11,15}))
```

Comment: Thanks Scott, much nicer and neater .